# Get referrer value in express?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a domain. I have two applications using this domain:

```
www.mydomain.com/first

www.mydomain.com/second
```

I do a redirect from `www.mydomain.com/first` to `www.mydomain.com/second` via the command: `res.redirect('/second');`

I'd like the application located at `www.mydomain.com/second` to then do a redirect back to `www.mydomain.com/first` dynamically (not via hardcoding the address).

So I was thinking that `www.mydomain.com/second` could get the request referrer field via the command: `req.get('Referrer')`. I was expecting this to return the value either `www.mydomain.com/first`, `/first` or `first` but it returns `undefined`.

How do I get a hold of the value?

Comment: It sounds to me like you're creating an infinite loop where first redirects to second which redirects to first which redirects to second  and so on...

Comment: In HTTP it is `referer` (notice one 'r').

Comment: @zeronone - The Express doc says that "the Referrer and Referer fields are interchangeable" with `req.get()` here: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.get

Comment: @jfriend00 Not really. The second application will set a cookie which is required by the first domain. So it may appear so, but the logic behind it is sound :)

Comment: @zeronone Tried both. Same result I'm afraid!

Comment: I think you're banking on something that isn't in the spec.  From the little bit I've read on this, the Referer header when redirecting to /second is not set to be /first.  If what you're trying to do is to let your server know that the when the request comes in for /second that it came from a redirect, then you should either set a cookie or use a query parameter on the redirect URL.  Your server can then see that.  A query parameter would probably be better because it's temporal, but you could also set a cookie for the server to see and then remove the cookie when it is seen.

Answer (score 0):

Because you want both applications to live on the same domain you can create a wrapper app that holds both 'children'.

```
var express = require('express');

var app1 = express();
app1.get('/first', function(req, res) {
  res.send('response from the first app');
})

var app2 = express();
app2.get('/second', function(req, res) {
  res.send('response from the second app');
});

var app = express();
app.use(app1);
app.use(app2);

app.listen(1337);
```

Because both apps now live on the same domain, you can redirect to what ever url you want as if it was within the same app.